# Average date of visiting website

Tags: mysql, sql

I'd like to know the average dates per week that users have been visited the website 'A'. If the user hasn't visited the website 'A', I exclude the data (e.g., id = 2). And I also need to consider the date range (limit it to a week range, e.g., 01-JAN-2018 to 07-JAN-2018)

Sample input (Table:User)

```
id   date           website
1    01-JAN-2018    A
1    03-JAN-2018    B
1    04-JAN-2018    C
1    04-JAN-2018    C
2    03-JAN-2018    C
3    03-JAN-2018    A
3    05-JAN-2018    B
4    05-JAN-2018    A
```

The first step will like this:

```
id   date           website
1    01-JAN-2018    A
1    03-JAN-2018    B
1    04-JAN-2018    C
1    04-JAN-2018    C
3    03-JAN-2018    A
3    05-JAN-2018    B
4    05-JAN-2018    A
```

The output will only return the average dates that users visiting websites (including ABC). In this case, user 1 visited three days a week (ignore duplicates) and user 3 visited two days a week. The average dates of hits will be sum(days)/number of users.

My first thought:

```
SELECT COUNT(Date), Date
FROM user
WHERE id IN (
  SELECT id FROM user
  WHERE web = 'A'
);
```

Assume that I only want to consider this week range (01-JAN-2018 to 07-JAN-2018). I want to figure out the average of dates of visiting in one week. Any thoughts for this? Thanks!

[Link for Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/6eccc0/17)

Comment: The demo is in MySQL so I removed the Postgres tag.

Comment: I haven't the faintest idea how the "2" is calculated.

Comment: Store dates as dates

Answer (score 0):

If you want to group by hits in a week, you might try something more like this:

```
select year(STR_TO_DATE(date,'%d-%b-%y')) year, 
  weekofyear(STR_TO_DATE(date,'%d-%b-%y')) week,   
  count(*) hits
from user
group by year(STR_TO_DATE(date,'%d-%b-%y')), weekofyear(STR_TO_DATE(date,'%d-%b-%y'))
```

The group by is the key: this will group all the hits for a particular week together, whereas `group by date` will keep each day separate.

If you want an average for multiple weeks, you would need to use this query as a subquery, and do an average on the count column.

And as was stated in comments, this would be a LOT easier (not to mention more efficient) if the date was stored as a `date` and not as a `varchar`